# Editing textbox value using switch button in matlab appdersigner

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have been working on a project I should do in MATLAB Appdesigner. What I am trying to do is when the Switch button is pressed, the value of the textbox changes to my desired value.(This just only a bit of the project, not all of it). For instance, as illustrated below, if the user clicks on the switch button to set it on **Transient mode**, the value in the textbox automatically changes to a specific number.

[image: Click to see the image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Thank you for mentioning your project specifications, but what is your associated question? Stack Overflow is not a place to get free code, so please [edit] the question to ask an actual question. Preferably add the code you used to create that image, see [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a callback to your switch button. Assuming the text field is called `EditField` and the switch is called `Switch`, this call back will change the `EditField` value to `10` every time you change it to `Transient`:

```matlab
% Value changed function: Switch
function SwitchValueChanged(app, event)
    value = app.Switch.Value;
    if strcmp(value, 'Transient')
        app.EditField.Value = '10';
    end
end
```

Note that the value of the switch is whatever you wrote on the interface, so if you change `Transient` or `Steady` to something else, you will have to change your code. Also note that `EditField.Value` expects a char array.